# How to switch childViewControllers in a ContainerViewController (load a new one, "delete" the old one)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Okay, so here's what I plan (I haven't done it yet):
I want to have a `container ViewController` that holds 3 `ViewControllers`:

1. **InfoVC**: A small "info" section at the top
2. **MenuVC**: A menu (placed below InfoVC's `view`) to select pages to show in ContentVC
3. **ContentVC**: `ViewControllers` that represent different pages (like `OverviewContentVC`, `MessagesContentVC`, ...)

**InfoVC** and **MenuVC** should always remain kind of static. They don't change.
But when you select a page inside the `MenuVC.view` the **ContentVC** should load the corresponding content `ViewController`. That means, it needs to delete/deinit the current content `ViewController` (and remove it from the `container ViewController`) and replace it with a new one.

I'm not sure how to do that.

Below are some thoughts I had about this. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Maybe my approach isn't quite right.

---

First, I would add `contentVC` as property to my `Container View Controller`:

```
var contentVC: UIViewController?
```

Then, in some method (`viewDidLoad` e.g.) I would add `contentVC` as child:

```
contentVC = OverviewContenVC() // default VC
self.addChildViewController(contentVC!)
contentVC!.view.frame = ...
self.view.addSubview(contentVC!.view)
contentVC!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Now, the user taps on the menu and wants to get to `MessagesContentVC`. That's my idea:

```
contentVC!.removeFromParentViewController()
contentVC!.view.removeFromSuperview()
contentVC = MessagesContentVC() // does this deinit OverviewContentVC?

// Do the same steps as above to add the new childVC
```

Obviously, I could combine these two code snippets and put them into one `method`. This is only to demonstrate my thoughts.

Also, you could do all sorts of animating.

But I'm not sure if this is an acceptable solution. For example, what if `MessagesContentVC` takes several seconds to load (which would be bad, but what if)? Maybe I could put this code into a background thread?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi @Quantm did you thought of using UIPageViewController inside a container view, so you can add how many controller you want?

Comment: Nice idea. I will take a look into this (I would implement it without a data source to prevent the swiping gesture). But what about performance? Does a pageViewController only init the viewController it needs?

Comment: Okay, it looks like the doesn't really work. UIPageViewController don't seem to be suited for that. I don't need an order of pages and stuff.